# Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none. Is this necessary?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-experience, ask-question-wizard-2018

Is this message necessary? It seems like a counter-intuitive extra step.

[image]

Comment: It's necessary when questions don't pass the test. If they didn't include this message on success, I wonder how long it would take before someone asked on Meta "Why doesn't the automated system always check my questions?"

Comment: I understand the necessity for the message when there's *something* to do, but there's nothing here. You literally just have to send the question a second time.

Comment: Btw. just because the automated system didn't find anything doesn't mean that the question is really ready to be published, strictly speaking.

Comment: Our automated system checked for ways to improve this comment and found none!

Comment: It's a confidence boost, though i hope it's accurate enough such that the majority of cases that receive this box are actually good questions.

Comment: lol, nice find Gabriel. How do you find none anyway? Anyone seen none lately? Fairly certain that should read: "Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and had no suggestions."

Comment: @TravisJ "but we found none" is actually a [reasonably common](https://ludwig.guru/s/we+found+none) phrase, though I agree it sounds silly to find something that isn't something.

Comment: But maybe *you* as a non-automated human should still re check the question to make sure it is good ...  (I think the extra step is good, just the message is missleading)

Comment: I can already see the meta question about : ' "SO Mod" abusing power  going against SO it self. SO already validate that my question was legitimate!'. Read "SO mod" as any user that voted on the question. And "Abusing power" as downvoting or close/duplicate vote.

Comment: As a chronic asker, this is driving me CRAZY :(

Comment: As for @Davy's point, just put a banner at the top of the question AFTER it's posted that says "Your question was checked and passed, yada, yada, yada. Here's a cookie.".

Comment: Since Stack Overflow the company isn't going to add this, who wants to whip up a userscript that detects the "ready to publish" notice and does the necessary question resubmission?

Comment: This seems pointless and needless.  Not the review itself... the fact that I, as a poster have to essentially re-post if there was no issues.  Submit it, and if it's good, just publish it. If you're worried about that confusing some people, put a banner over the newly-posted question saying 'You passed review! Here's how your question appears' and be done with it.  You could also change the button itself to say 'Review and publish' which itself is also explicit.

Comment: Another issue with this design... forcing a user to *always* have to click through will desensitize them to what's in that message.  They'll just know 'When it appears, I have to mash it again!'  Now contrast that to showing it only when there's an issue.  They'll be 'Hey... wait... this is new!  Lemme take a look!'  In other words, the current design is actively training them to ignore it, while simultaneously annoying users.  Does *that* sound like a good design?!

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate, sorry... just realize I stole your 'banner' idea above.  :)  What do you think about my comment on desensitizing the user?

Comment: 100% agreed. It's habit now.  "Oh yeah, after I hit post I have to scroll down and hit post again".  Of course I have no idea what happens if it *doesn't* pass inspection.  Hopefully you can't simply just press post again and it would jar any posters out of their routine.

Comment: This is an extremely poorly thought out message.  It strongly implies that to the user that the system thinks their question is good.  When in fact what actually happened is that there were no strong red flags in the question.  When the question gets downvoted and closed, the user will be more upset than usual.. "But you said my question was good!!"  Wording is important.

Comment: The interesting thing is that 18 months have passed without change, or did it change (not having asked for a while). If yes it would be an extreme version of never change a running system.